# Different python package requirements for 32 and 64 bit

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

**Problem**

My code depends on two packages `A` and `B`.

Recently I found an issue with the packages compatibility: maintainers of package `A` stopped releasing whl packages for 32 bit Python, while maintainers of package `B` removed some functionality, which package `A` relies on. Since package `A` relies on some functionality in package `B`, the code fails in runtime. When using 64 bit Python the problem goes away - all packages are synced nicely.

Of course I can manually suppress the upper version for package `B`, but it does not make sense for 64 bit version.
It is preferable to use the newest versions for 64 bit Python.
Yet it is necessary to allow Python 32 bit run smoothly as well, with older package versions, which I can define myself.

**Question**

I wonder if there is an opportunity to specify different package requirements for different bit versions.

Currently in `setup.py` we have `install_requires` field,
but this is generic and not bit-specific.

**Extra info**

Excerpt from `setup.py`:

```py
install_requires=[
    'A',
    'B',
]
```

I install my package in a dev environment:

```bash
$ pip install -e .
```

**Update**

I probably should have mentioned explicitly that here I want to differentiate between different Python bit versions (32 bit vs 64 bit) rather than OS architecture.

The only solution I managed to come up with is this:

```py
is_32_bit = sys.maxsize <= 2**32
if is_32_bit:
    install_requires = ['A<=1.0', 'B<=1.0']
else:
    install_requires = ['A']


setup(
    ...
    install_requires=install_requires,
)
```

Answer (score 6):

#### Update

This is unfortunately not a solution to this problem since one cannot cover the case of 32bit Python installed on a 64bit OS using environment markers. `platform_machine` only gives you the architecture on the OS level, not for Python installation itself.

#### Original answer

You should be able to achieve this using the `platform_machine` environment marker:

```
install_requires=[
    "A<1.0;platform_machine!='x86_64' and platform_machine!='amd64'",
    "A>=1.0;platform_machine=='x86_64' or platform_machine=='amd64'"
]
```

Now `A>=1.0` will be installed on 64bit architecture (`x86_64` targets Unix, `amd64` targets Windows) and `A<1.0` everywhere else. If you need fine-grained control over more architectures (e.g. separate `arm` from `i686` etc), add more requirement strings.

Reference: [PEP 508, Environment Markers](https://peps.python.org/pep-0508/#environment-markers).

Comment: Thank you for the answer and giving a great hint to env markers! However, I noticed that platform.machine() returns AMD64 for Python 32 bit, which is run on 64 bit OS. So, it does not exactly solve my problem. Please take a look at the update in my question. Is there any way to make it cleaner? Thank you!

Comment: @MaximIvanov hmm, then this solution sucks unfortunately :-( you can't distinguish between 32bit and 64bit Python via environment markers. The only problem with evaluating `sys.maxsize` you proposed is that you can't distribute wheels anymore once you put this code in `setup.py`, so you can only use source dists. However, I can't think of a better solution than this. Mind putting it into an answer of yours?